How to add a condition check for null in jolt?
I am new to jolt mapping . Below is the input and expected output.
Scenario 1 :
Input :
{
  "name": "Fred",
  "phone": [
    {
      "mobile": "1112223333"
    }
  ]
}

Expected OUTPUT:
{
  "name" : "Fred",
  "customer" : {
    "mobile" : "1112223333"
  }
}

Scenario 2 :
Input :
{
  "name": "Fred",
  "phone": null
}

Expected OUTPUT:
{
  "name" : "Fred",
  "customer" : {
    "mobile" : "000"
  }
}

I tried the following spec. Scenario 1 works as expected , however scenario 2 fails and does not read the null check.
SPEC:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "name": "name",
      "phone": {
        "null": {
          "#000": "customer.mobile"
        },
        "*": {
          "mobile": "customer.mobile"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

I added a null condition to default the "customer.mobile" to 000 if it is null, otherwise use the existing input value . Any assistance is appreciated thanks!

You can use ~ symbol as an attribute prefix in order to check out nullity or existence within a modify spec such as :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "phone": {
        "~mobile": "000" // means if "phone" does not exist or is null, then make it be "000"
      }
    }
  },
  {//in order to resemble the cases each other
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "phone": "=toList"
    }
  },
  {//return the result as desired
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "phone": {
        "*": {
          "mobile": "customer.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

